# Как отсортировать двумерный массив по количеству отрицательных элементов

Tags: c, массивы

Получил следующее задание: отсортировать строки двумерного массива по количеству отрицательных элементов. 
Суть в том , что могу найти и количество элементов и номер строки в котором они расположены , но не могу это связать с сортировкой самого массива(его строк)

```
int matrix[A][A]; //какая-то матрица
int array[A][2];
    count=0;
    c=0;
    for ( i = 0; i < A; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < A; j++)
        {
            //находим отрицательные элементы
            if (matrix[i][j]<0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    //записываем в первое значение номер строки
        array[c][0]=i;
    //во второе значение записываем количество отрицательных элементов 
        array[c][1]=count;
        c++;
        count=0;
    }
```

записал значения в другой двумерный массив [A][2](#define A 6) 
проблема  состоит в том , что не могу **придумать** логически как отсортировать один массив по значениям. 
По возможности подскажите способ проще.

Answer (score 0):

Разбейте задачу на этапы.

На первом этапе, запишите в промежуточный одномерный массив количества отрицательных элементов в строках.

На втором этапе, сортируйте этот массив, одновременно переставляя строки в выходной матрице.

Поздравляю, вы великолепны!